# How does render() actually execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project and I have created an interesting challenge for myself.

```
render() {
    const sysObjs = this.state.systemObjects;
    const jsonPackage = sysObjs[0];

    if(typeof jsonPackage === 'undefined'){
    console.log("undefined!!!")
    } else {
      //let jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonPackage.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"));
      console.log(jsonPackage.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"));
    }
   
    console.log(jsonPackage.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"));
```

If I run that it will fail and it will fail on the last line of the snippet and it will fail because from the perspective of that line of code jsonPackage is undefined and we get a "cannot read property 'replaceAll' of undefined. That makes sense to me as doing any sort of operation on something that is undefined would fairly difficult. The part that is confusing me though is that if I remove that last line then the code will execute. That's confusing to me because that console.log is also there within the if-else block so I would imagine that both should throw errors but they don't. In fact if I run that after removing the last line I will actually get both sections of the if-else block to log to the console and that tells me that this is executing in a way that I don't understand. Can anyone explain what's happening for me? At the root here something is doing something such that the const jsonPackage is not populated immediately when it is set so I'm curious how react actually handles something like that.

Lastly, I commented out that line because that line throws "Unhandled Rejection(Error) A cross-origin error was thrown." I'm also not too sure what that actually means either as it wasn't covered in the course I took.

Comment: Checking the code closely the last ``console.log`` is not within the ``if-else`` block. That is why it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render()` is called each time your component's state updates. It can also get called in a number of other circumstances, but I think that's the relevant one for this situation.

You're not showing all of your code, but there is probably something running on mount or something similar that updates `this.state.systemObjects`.

On the *first* render of the component, `this.state.systemObjects` is `undefined`. So, if you have your `console.log(jsonPackage.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\"));` line in at the end of your render, it will fail because it can't do an operation on `undefined`. However, with it commented out, it runs fine, because it goes through the `if(typeof jsonPackage === 'undefined'){` section of your `if` clause and not the `else` clause, where an operation is done on `jsonPackage`.

Then, once `systemObjects` is updated, `render` runs *again*. On that pass, `systemObjects` now is *not* `undefined`, so the `else` clause gets run -- since you don't have an undefined value any more, that else clause runs fine.

Your cross-origin error is not caused by any code you've shown -- it's probably caused by an API request somewhere. There are plenty of answers on SO about what can cause those.

Comment: I think speaks to your wisdom that you were able to identify a portion of my code without seeing it. Yes, I was using componenetDidMount earlier in code. I decided to use it to put what I need in the state then start calling it from the state. That makes more sense than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question.  This is happening because the first time your code is executing, `jsonPackage` is not defined. This is why both blocks of your `if` statement are logging, because during the first pass though it is `undefined` and during the second it is, which will cause the `else` block to fire.

And this is why your code is breaking, during the first pass through of `render`, `jsonPackage` is not defined which will throw an error.

Its not really possible to explain why it's not defined the first time around without seeing the rest of your code. As a rule of thumb however, you should generally never assume that a React state value will always be defined and add checks accordingly.